# How to Pass List to Service Class in c# from another class

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I am having a Service class which implements an Interface. In this class I am using List which is loaded from excel.
I have to load the list only once at the beginning of program. So I have load List at Console_Load and pass the list to Service Class and get in another List.  However the values becomes empty inside IService Members. Please help on this

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 0):

If your instance mode is not [singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx) you'll probably need to store the list in a static member during the startup of your service